# Finding a Module's path, using the Module object

Tags: julia

What is the sane way to go from a `Module` object to a path to the file in which it was declared?
To be precise, I am looking for the file where the keyword `module` occurs.

The indirect method is to find the location of the automatically defined `eval` method in each module.
`moduleloc(mm::Module) = first(functionloc(mm.eval, (Symbol,)))`

for example

```
moduleloc(mm::Module) = first(functionloc(mm.eval, (Symbol,)))
using DataStructures
moduleloc(DataStructures)
```

Outputs:

```
/home/oxinabox/.julia/v0.6/DataStructures/src/DataStructures.jl
```

This indirect method works, but it feels like a bit of a kludge.
Have I missed some inbuilt function to do this?

I will remind answered that Modules are not the same thing as packages.
Consider the existence of submodules, or even modules that are being loaded via `include`ing some abolute path that is outside the package directory or loadpath.

Comment: What is it for? Btw: *Files and file names are mostly unrelated to modules; modules are associated only with module expressions. One can have multiple files per module, and multiple modules per file* ([source](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/)) And define sane! Is `mp(m::Module) = ccall(:jl_gf_invoke_lookup, Any, (Any, UInt), Tuple{typeof(m.eval), Symbol}, typemax(UInt)).func.file` sane in your understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure why you find looking at the location of `eval` insane.  It's automatically defined in all `module`s.  Methods store their paths; I don't believe modules do.

Comment: @Liso  Every module has exactly 1 file that includes the block `module name ... end`. Yes, I agree, there might be multiple modules in the same file (but that doesn't mean they are not in that file), and modules contents (but not declaration) can be spread over multiple files via `include` (and even 1 file may be the contents of 2 modules). But it is the headword file I am looking for. As for define insane: perhaps indirect is a better word, I will edit.

Comment: Question "what is it for?" is important. Because if there is good reason then perhaps path could be stored. If path is not stored what else could be more direct way? If it is for possibility to edit then `@edit m.eval("")` is not good? If it is for documentation perhaps other way is more sane than introspection?

Comment: Primarily I want to know this for pure reasons.
Secondly though,
I am considering it as an option to find files that are located relative to a module  when that module is in a package eg LISCENSE.md
Solutions based on knowing the package name won't actually work, because module name != PackageName.
One option might be to search all a modules parents until I find the penultimate one, which is likely the package name, though I am not certain it is, and then uses a Package based  option.
But as to if that would work or not, that would be a separate and different question. Thus pure question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules simply do not store the file location where they were defined. You can see that for yourself in [their definition in C](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/307773217a79d267910aba9af9a12310d9f704d8/src/julia.h#L423-L433).  Your only hope is to look through the bindings they hold.

Methods, on the other hand, do store their file location.  And `eval` is the one function that is defined in every single `module` (although not `baremodule`s).  Slightly more correct might be:

```
moduleloc(mm::Module) = first(functionloc(mm.eval, (Any,)))
```

as that more precisely mirrors the auto-defined eval method.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking for a programmatic way of doing it you can use the `methods` function.

```
using DataFrames
locations = methods(DataFrames.readtable).ms
```

It's for all methods but it's hardly difficult to find the right one unless you have an enormous number of methods that differ only in small ways.

Comment: I am looking for a programatic way.
Also I suggest removing the `.ms`.
It is not getting you anything when  the result still has to be inspected by hand anyway.
(methods uses `functionloc` under the hood, btw)

Answer (score 0):

There is now [`pathof`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.pathof-Tuple%7BModule%7D):

```
using DataStructures

pathof(DataStructures)
"/home/ederag/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0/src/DataStructures.jl"
```

See also: [pkgdir](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.pkgdir-Tuple%7BModule%7D).

```
pkgdir(DataStructures)
"/home/ederag/.julia/packages/DataStructures/59MD0"
```

Tested with julia-1.7.3

Answer (score -1):

`require` obviously needs to perform that operation. Looking into `loading.jl`, I found that finding the module path has changed a bit recently: in [v0.6.0](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/903644385b91ed8d95e5e3a5716c089dd1f1b08a/base/loading.jl#L83), there is a function

```
load_hook(prefix::String, name::String, ::Void)
```

which you can call "manually":

```
julia> Base.load_hook(Pkg.dir(), "DataFrames", nothing)
"/home/philipp/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/DataFrames.jl"
```

However, this has changed to the better in the [current master](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/95285623b15a1ca9efbcd24db98b7613d71f3aa7/base/loading.jl#L90); there's now a function `find_package`, which we can copy:

```
macro return_if_file(path)
    quote
        path = $(esc(path))
        isfile(path) && return path
    end
end

function find_package(name::String)
    endswith(name, ".jl") && (name = chop(name, 0, 3))
    for dir in [Pkg.dir(); LOAD_PATH]
        dir = abspath(dir)
        @return_if_file joinpath(dir, "$name.jl")
        @return_if_file joinpath(dir, "$name.jl", "src", "$name.jl")
        @return_if_file joinpath(dir,   name,     "src", "$name.jl")
    end
    return nothing
end
```

and add a little helper:

```
find_package(m::Module) = find_package(string(module_name(m)))
```

Basically, this takes `Pkg.dir()` and looks in the "usual locations".

Additionally, `chop` in v0.6.0 doesn't take these additional arguments, which we can fix by adding

```
chop(s::AbstractString, m, n) = SubString(s, m, endof(s)-n)
```

Also, if you're not on Unix, you might want to care about the definitions of `isfile_casesensitive` above the linked code.

---

And if you're not so concerned about corner cases, maybe this is enough or can serve as a basis:

```
function modulepath(m::Module)
    name = string(module_name(m))
    Pkg.dir(name, "src", "$name.jl")
end
```

Comment: Your first code does not work for `Modules` it works for packages, as you so labelled it.
Consider when applied to a submodule: `find_package(TensorFlow.train)==nothing`.
vs `moduleloc(TensorFlow.train) "/home/wheel/oxinabox/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/train.jl"`

Your `modulepath` also fails: `modulepath(TensorFlow.train)="/home/wheel/oxinabox/.julia/v0.6/train/src/train.jl"`

Answer (score -1):

```
julia> Pkg.dir("DataStructures")
"/home/liso/.julia/v0.7/DataStructures"
```

Edit: I now realized that you want to use Module object!

```
julia> m = DataStructures
julia> Pkg.dir(repr(m))
"/home/liso/.julia/v0.7/DataStructures"
```

Edit2: I am not sure if you are trying to find path to module or to object defined in module (I hope that parsing path from next result is easy):

```
julia> repr(which(DataStructures.eval, (String,)))
"eval(x) in DataStructures at /home/liso/.julia/v0.7/DataStructures/src/DataStructures.jl:3"
```

Comment: as I said Module,  you were right the second time. I have updated the question to be clearer by putting in a function with type constraints.
(Also your third code is pointless, `repr(which)` calls `functionloc` (used in my question) as part of building that string. Why would I build that string, and then parse it out?)

Comment: In anycase, your solution based on `Pkg.dir` works only for Packages.
Not for modules. Modules!=Packages.
Consider submodules as one of the cases that are obviously different.
`Pkg.dir(repr(TensorFlow.train)) == "/home/wheel/oxinabox/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow.train"`: Which is wrong -- no such Tensorflow.train directory exists.
vs
`moduleloc(TensorFlow.train)
"/home/wheel/oxinabox/.julia/v0.6/TensorFlow/src/train.jl"`

which is right.